# Boost libraries and dlls

Tags: c++, boost

I have downloaded boost package, and now I want to make dll files and libraries out of the source, but on the net there is no explain for how to do that? Also, I am not sure how to build it to get include files too or whatever comes from it. It would be nice if someone enlighten me with the knowledge how to set up boost for the windows platform. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read this? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/more/getting_started/windows.html

Comment: I have got lib files, but I wanted dynamic libraries too. How to acquire it?

Comment: Look here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-build-binaries-from-source

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10866511/825637) for including libraries:

> You'll need to include the library in the linkers input.
>
> For VS:
>
> 1. Put the library's file in the solution's root folder. (you might not have to do this in general for some libraries)
> 2. At Visual Studios menu go to Project --> [SolutionName] properties.
> 3. A dialog will open. navigate to Configuration Properties --> Linker --> Input
> 4. At "Additional Dependencies" add the name of the library. (it'll probably be *.lib)

Comment: Well, the thing is I have no problem with it, since I have already explicitly included in VC/include directory all headers and cpp files and libs in VC/libs. The thing is I don't know how to acquire dll files, so I can have dynamic libraries, not dependent on what place my code cumulates.

Comment: @SerenityStackHoolder099 Those files should be included in your download. Perhaps you didn't download what you were looking for.